# Passing array to method used on array member in c#

Tags: c#, arrays

i was wandering if there is a way to pass an array to a function that is used on its members( kind of like how you pass the "this" parameter to object).

instead of this:

```cs
void public foo(A[] arr){}

void main(){

arr[i].foo(arr);
}
```

this:

```cs
void public foo(A[] arr){}

void main(){
arr[i].foo();
}
```

edit: arr is array of A, foo belongs to A
sorry for bad explanation first question.

Comment: You could create an [extension method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods).

Comment: If you go down the extension method route, I suspect you will want `arr.foo()` not `arr[i].foo()`.

Comment: Sounds like you want to just do a foreach over the array and call foo on each item?     `foreach(A a in arr)foo(a);`  Or am I misunderstanding the question?

Comment: You mean like this,

    `void public foo(data_type var)
    {
        ....
    }

    void main()
    {
        foo(arr[i])
    }`

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay an extension method wont do because i want it to run on the objects inside the array and not the array itself

Comment: If `A` is a class or struct you defined yourself then `foo` should just be a method in it. Otherwise you can also create an extension method taking a `this A` parameter

Comment: No, I don't think so (assuming I understand the question, which I'm not sure I do) - The instance of `A` could be a member of any number of arrays (or none at all). You would have to explicitly pass the array to `A.foo()`.

Comment: To improve your question it would be really helpful if you included some more detail in the sample code. Are we to assume that `arr` is an `A[]`? and that `foo` belongs to the `A` class? And where does `main` live? In the sample it appears to live in the same class as `foo`. Please spend a bit more time clarifying the question and sample code.

Answer (score 1):

So... if I understand correctly. You want to call an item in the array, with a reference to the array.

But you don't want to pass that reference to the array?

I can only think of a working solution where you make a new class that encapsulates the array[] and create an add method, that upon adding handles the reference binding. (so passing a ref of itself to the added object). So that the items in the array hold a reference to the array.

or maybe you can do some nifty stuff using indexers:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/indexers/

Hope this helps!